# T4 templates to generate code based on current project

Tags: c#, t4

In the current project in visual studio I would have a class that looks something like this

```
public class DbContextBuilderFactory
{
    public List<String> Test { get { return new List<string>{ "adsa", "adas"};} }
}
```

Can I then from a t4 template file load the assembly and find the class and iterate over the Test Property and generate a .cs file with a class wit properties based on the list?

expected output.

```
public class OutPutClass
{
    public int adsa{get;set;}
    public int adas{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes, although you'll have to add some directives like `<#@ import namespace="TheNameSpaceYouWillUse" #>` and `<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>` so Visual Studio can first compile the T4 and then bundle it with the actual assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a TemplateManager.tt file which contains some reusable logic. The internals of this tt file are almost identical to any .cs file:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Namespace.With.DbContextBuilderFactory" #>

<#+
// Keep code you want to reuse in a separate tt file
public class TemplateManager
{
  // properties
  // parse DbContextBuilderFactory
  public static IEnumerable<string> ParseDbContextBuilderFactory()
  {
    DbContextBuilderFactory dbf= new DbContextBuilderFactory();
    return dbf.Tests;
  }
}
```

Then in your main t4 template

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude.tt"#>
<#@ include file="TemplateManager.tt"#>
<#@import namespace="System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices" #>
<#
    // preamble
    List<Values> values = TemplateManager.ParseDbContextBuilderFactory();   
    WriteOutput(code, values, namespaceName);
    FileManager.Process(); // or something
#>
<#+
//_=_
public void WriteOutput(CodeGenerationTools code, List<string> values, string namespaceName)
{
PopIndent();
#>
namespace <#=code.Escape(namespaceName)#>
{
    public class OutPutClass
    {
        <#+
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
        #>
        public int <#=code.Escape(value)#> {get; set; }
        <#
        } // foreach
        #>
    }
}
<#
} // WriteOutput
#>
```